# Drawing an ASCII tree using nested for-loops

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I am practising my programming skills with a rather common problem, to draw an ASCII tree composed of a letter (let's say x's) to draw a tree.

Ie:

```
Prompt: Enter the number of lines for your tree: 5
Output: 
   x
  xxx
 xxxxx
xxxxxxx
   x
```

The solution I have is currently working as I want it to. I am only missing one feature (which is part of my question). **The issue is, I do not understand the for-loop conditionals I have used. Yes, I did get help from another individual and I still do not understand their logic, but it works. Please, please, please explain to me how the for loop conditionals are actually working for me to draw what I want. x.x
Furthermore, I am unable to draw the last "stump" of the tree, the final x in the last row.**

Here is my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lines = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of lines: ");
            string LinesAsString = Console.ReadLine();
            lines = Convert.ToInt32(LinesAsString);
            print(lines);
        }


        public static void print(int lines)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < lines-i-1; a++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }

                for (int y = 0; y < i*2 + 1; y++)
                {

                    Console.Write("x");


                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }





        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `for` loop prints the left padding (all spaces). The expression `lines - i - 1` comes form the fact that you need to center the tree and you know that line `0` has a single `x`, line `1` has 3 (`xxx`), line `2` has 5 (`xxxxx`) and so on. But the number of left spaces depends on the total number of lines the tree has, therefore you need to take the `lines` into account as well as the index of the current line (which is the value of the variable `i`). To figure out the relationship between these two, you can just try with a small number of levels, let's say 3:

```
__x     2 for the 1st line.
_xxx    1 for the 2nd line.
xxxxx   0 for the 3rd line.
```

The second `for` loop prints the `x`s. It knows that for the first line (`i = 0`) it needs to print a single `x`, so when `i` is `0`, `y` needs to be `1`, therefore the `+ 1`. The `* 2` comes from the progression `i * 2 + 1 = {1, 3, 5, 7...}` which is the number of `x`s in each line.

To print the last stub character you can use the same logic as in the first `for` loop, inserting the number of spaces for the first line followed by a single `x`.

```
Console.Write(new String(' ', lines - 1) + "x");
```

This should be added just after the `for` loop that contains the two other loops.

Comment: Dumb question - what does i stand for when you mean 'index of the current line'?

Comment: I meant the variable `i` which indicates which line is being printed to the output in each iteration of the `for` that encloses the two others. Just edited the answer to clarify that point.

Comment: Thanks - this is very helpful. I seem to understand it now. My only concern is, in the future, with similar problems, I'll probably need help with this sort of stuff! Any tips for problem solving strategies of this kind? :p

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

Each iteration of the first for loop draws a line. Supposing you have 4 lines (I am not considering the one with the lonely x):

line 1 (i=0): 3 spaces 1 x 
 
line 2 (i=1): 2 spaces 3 x 
line 3 (i=2): 1 spaces 5 x 
line 4 (i=3): 0 spaces 7 x

From these, you can obtain a relation between the number of spaces, x's, the line index i and the number of lines.

```
    spaces = (lines - i) - 1 // decreases by one every iteration starting at lines - 1
    x = i * 2 + 1 // the odd numbers in increasing order
```

The first loop draw the spaces and the second one the x's

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 8-i-1; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i*2+1; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("X");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
//solution to your stump problem
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)//the no. 4 means that you stump will be made from four X's
{
     for (int x = 0; x < 8-count-1; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
        
    }
     Console.Write("X");
     Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```